# How to find out distinct count of people by date based on conditions relating to previous dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, date

This is a problem on Hackerrank. Basically, we have to find out the unique count of people who made submissions, group by date. However the catch is, if the contest starts on March 1st, then for March 4th for eg, we have to consider only those people who actually made submissions on March 1st,2nd and 3rd as well. The code to find that out is below:-

```
SELECT   submission_date, 
         Count(DISTINCT hacker_id) unique_count 
FROM     ( 
                  SELECT   d.submission_date, 
                           v.hacker_id, 
                           Count(DISTINCT v.submission_date) cnt 
                  FROM     ( 
                                           SELECT DISTINCT submission_date 
                                           FROM            submissions 
                                                           --ORDER BY submission_date 
                           ) d, 
                           submissions v 
                  WHERE    v.submission_date <= d.submission_date 
                  GROUP BY d.submission_date, 
                           v.hacker_id ) e 
WHERE    CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),Day(submission_date)) = cnt 
GROUP BY submission_date 
         --ORDER BY submission_date 
) table2
```

The table submissions has 4 columns :-
submission_date, submission_id, hacker_id, score
If we have the sample data :-

```
3-1-2018, a5, 200, 98
3-1-2018, d6, 400, 96
3-2-2018, e7, 200, 91
3-2-2018, v5, 205, 82
```

Here, hacker 200 has 2 submissions while hackers 205 and 400 have made 1 submission each.

For date 3-1-2018, we will count total no. Of submissions as 2 but for 3-2-2018, we will count only 1 since hacker 205 didn't make a submission on the previous day.

The part iam not able to understand is the part where the convert varchar max(day, submission date) is used.

Can anyone please explain this code?

Thanks,

Comment: You might want to include some sample data to get your point across.

Comment: that is where your comparing a cnt (which is most likely a number) to day which is also a number.

Comment: the inner query e is a list of submission dates and hackers, and how many submissions they have made by that date.  The outer query queries e, and only returns a record if the number of submissions by the hacker equals the DAY number.  So if it is the 4th, the hacker has to have counted exactly 4 submissions by that date.  The reason for varchar max is unclear

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen added.

Comment: I'm sure you can remove the CONVERT, it simply compares a string to a numeric, but the actual 'things' made into strings are always numbers, Day(submission_date) = cnt  will work the same I believe.  Consider the following experiment - select 1 where 1 = convert(varchar(max) , 3-2)

Comment: I think [cnt] in the where clause should be evaluate to variable that you declare at the start of your select statement. Depending on some business logic. Because that line is going to filter out a LOT of your data. For example in code below what if your date is 10-29-2018; count(Distinct)  on v.submission_date will always be a small number given in your example case.

Comment: @Cato Oh, so if it's 3rd day, there should be 3 or more than 3 submissions? But what if one hacker makes 2 submissions on day 1, 0 on day 2?

Comment: then based on your where clause he will NOT show up.

Comment: Ok. Lemme have a minutet.thanks @junketsu.

Comment: you where clause should be along the lines of where [cnt] = @check_days and this variable should be declared top side as delcare .@check_days int = 3 (an example value) . this value should come from whatever business logic your trying to accomplish.

Comment: on the third, the count of past submissions including those on the third, has to be exactly 3 (= 3)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you to understand

```
create table #temp_date_eg
( business_date date null
)
insert into #temp_date_eg values
('2018-11-01')
,('2018-11-10')
,('2018-10-29')
,('2018-11-15')


select top 10 CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),Day(business_date)),business_date
from #temp_date_eg
```